# Print multidimensional array using php , array stored in associative format

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am learning php, while practising I had an issue. I have created a  multidimensional array with item values and am using a for loop to print those values but I am getting

> Error: undefined offset

The array format is associative.

Requirement:

1) print all values using for loop/foreach loop

2) if any associative array is empty avoid that

3) check whether it is array or single value like some values again have their own array

```
$item_list=array();  //multidimensional array with associative values
echo '<pre>';print_r($item_list);

Array
(
    [total_price] => 1200
    [item_1] => Array
        (
            [item_name1] => xyz
            [item_price1] => 100.00

        )

    [item_2] => Array
        (
            [item_name2] => abc
            [item_price2] => 200.00

        )


    [item_3] => 
    [item_4] => Array
        (
            [item_name3] => aaa
            [item_price3] => 402.00
        )

)
```

// code which I have used to echo all values

```
for ($row = 0; $row < count($item_list); $row++) {
  // if value contain array then go to nested for loop else print direct value
  echo "<ul>";
  for ($col = 0; $col < count($item_list[$row]); $col++) {

    //echo "<li>".$item_list[$row][$col]."</li>";
    echo "<li>".array_values($item_list[$row])[$col]."</li>";

  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: a `recursiveArrayIterator` might suit your needs

Comment: No, ijust want to print values according to their group for example   item_1: its name,price for item_2 its name ,price

Comment: can you please correct my code  so that it will print all values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array is associative, you can't access the values using a numeric index in a `for` loop. Instead, use a `foreach` loop over the elements:

```
foreach ($item_list as $key => $item_details) {
    if (is_array($item_details)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
        foreach ($item_details as $name => $value) {
            echo "\t$name: $value\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "$key: $item_details\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
total_price: 1200
item_1:
    item_name1: xyz
    item_price1: 100
item_2:
    item_name2: abc
    item_price2: 200
item_3: 
item_4:
    item_name3: aaa
    item_price3: 402
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/KBYfs)

Note it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve formatting wise, so I've just left the output in simple line format. It would be fairly easy to add `<ul>/<li>` structure to this.